# how can I make a service run on intervals in android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to make a service performs and action at intervals, with the help of [this article](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#java) I was able to set up a service and set and interval of 1000miliseconds to log to my console, but I noticed that the service only runs once. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
    class MessageService : Service() {

private var serviceLooper: Looper? = null
private var serviceHandler: ServiceHandler? = null

override fun onCreate() {
    val context:Context = this
    HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments", Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND).apply {
        start()
        serviceLooper = looper
        serviceHandler = ServiceHandler(context, looper)
    }
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    serviceHandler?.obtainMessage()?.also { msg ->
        msg.arg1 = startId
        serviceHandler?.sendMessage(msg)
    }

    return START_STICKY
}

override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? { return null}

override fun onDestroy() {}

private inner class ServiceHandler(context: Context, looper: Looper) : Handler(looper) {

    val baseContext = context
    override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
        val runnable = Runnable {
            Log.i("thread", "service has been called")
        }
        this.postDelayed(runnable, 1000)
    }
}
```

}

please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What part of this code do you expect will do the repeated logging?  As I read it you have a handler which accepts a message.  You send one message and it then logs after 1s.

Comment: Where does `looper` in `onCreate` get instantiated?

Comment: What does "the service only runs once" mean? Bear in mind that background services can only run for one minute on Android 8.0+, and that your work will stop when the phone goes asleep and the CPU powers done. Please understand that what you are doing is terrible for battery life, and so Google and device manufacturers are taking a lot of steps to prevent this sort of behavior.

Comment: @possum I expected the handler to repeat the logging.

Comment: @CommonsWare basically I want to run a listener as a service that listens if new SMS comes in on the phone.

Comment: There are broadcasts for that. You should not need to be trying to do work every second for that.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you're creating a NEW Handler using `val handler = Handler()` after the first correct "handleMessage()" call, so each `postDelayed()` will post the runnable in an "unmanaged" Handler (I call "unmanaged" because that just-created-one hasn't overridden the "handleMessage(..)" method).
You need to `postDelayed()` to `serviceHandler` and not to a new Handler. To fix you can use `this.postDelayed(...)` because you're inside ServiceHandler and you want to post the Runnable in the same Handler.

Comment: I just updated my code. but I am still having the same issue

Comment: A simple Service shares the UiThread/MainThread, so if the Main Activity/Application is busy or closed, the Service cannot work. Why not put a "Log.d(TEXT)" in "Service.onDestroy()" and on "ServiceThread.handleMessage()"? In this way you will know something more...